# Switch from ViewController to TabBarController

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have one small problem. I have iOS app in xcode and when I launch it, it comes with

TabBarController. But then, I need to go to another ViewController (there would be some

info with pictures) and after that, I need go back to main page with TabbarController, but

when I click to back button, It show up without Tabbar on the bottom... For more clear, I've made a scheme...

[Click to this link to show image scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O6hD.png)

Can anybody slove this please? Im working without storyboards, so I need it

programmatically. Thank you for every reply!

```
Steve
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your window.rootViewController is actually your UINavigationController. If you want the TabBar be present in all the screens then you need to make it your window.rootViewController.

Comment: thx for reply, but it isn exactly what I need... I will explain it again.

I have one View controller (called ViewControlllerMAIN) and second NavigationController (called RootViewController). In AppDelgate, I've got split them to one "tbc" TabBarController and everything is good, but I need to add some "Tips" for usnig app there and I want to fire it with a button in ViewControllerMAIN. When I do it, It works, but then, when I want to go back to ViewContollerMAIN (I use for it Modal switch) Tabbar goes away... So is any possibility, how can I do it? Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set it in your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TabBarController" owner:self options:nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = tbc;

    return YES;
}
```

Create a xib with a tabcontroller, drop a navigation controller inside tab bar.
Set the Class of the Viewcontroller and the nib name.

Inside the method of the Button, needs to be like:

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    Primeiro2ViewController *p2vc = [[Primeiro2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Primeiro2ViewController" bundle:nil];
    p2vc.title = @"Primeiro 2";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:p2vc animated:YES];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

If you need a sample, I upload for you later.